# Bike wheel help for newbie

Tags: wheels, beginner, heavy

I was wondering if someone could help me? I have recently bought a Specialized Allez Sport road bike (61cm frame) and due to my weight I’m looking to upgrade the wheel set straight away due to my weight 140kg. Having researched I have found that either Velocity Deep V or H Plus Son SL42 wheel sets would be suitable for my weight, but how do I know if they are suitable for my bike? Will they fit? Any help or advice would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Product recommendations are generally considered off-topic here, but you will probably get a general explanation about component compatibility. Both products you mention are rims. For complete wheels, you will also need hubs, spokes and someone to build them into a wheel.

Comment: You may look for wheels that have no weight limit mentioned in their description, many being limited to 120kg system (bike+rider) weight. You may also have wheels hand-built to your requirements. Which I believe is the more sensible approach.

Comment: A quick internet search reveals that the weight limit of this bike is at 125kg. It means that you don't just exceed the limit of the wheels but problems are likely to occur with the frame, the fork, the handlebars etc, making the ride dangerous because of possible material failures. In short, don't ride that bike!

Comment: The link is here: https://media.specialized.com/support/0000057489/0000057489.pdf

Answer (score 2):

There are a few questions and answers on this site about wheel compatibility, but here is what you need to know in your situation.

Obviously you need ISO 622 / 700c rim brake wheels.

Dropout spacing on the Allez Sport is standard road bike 130mm rear, 100mm front.

Rim bead seat width should be compatible with the tires you have, or intend to run. A beefier wheelset may have wider rims than those on the Allez. Note that rim width refers to the *inner* width of the rim where the tire bead engages. Searching on this site or the Internet will yield a chart of rim width to tire width compatibility.

As a heavier rider you may want to run slightly wider tires than the original 25mm. The Allez will probably accommodate 28mm tires. You can check by looking at the clearance between the current tires and frame.

Lastly, the *freehub body* that the rear sprocket cassette fits on only needs to be compatible with 9 or 10 speed cassettes. (11 speed cassettes require a wider freehub. 9 and 10 speed cassettes can be fitted with spacers, but 11 speed wheels will likely be more expensive.)

You actually have a massive choice of wheels available to you. Search this site for advice for wheels for heavier riders. Wheels aimed at touring bikes with high spoke counts (32 or more) seem to be what heavier riders go for.

Comment: One more think one should make sure is that the brakes are good enough. While it is mostly an issue with older roadbikes, some breaks are not able to stop the wheel from spinning fast enough. This problem will become more apparent with the weight of the rider being higher.

Answer (score 1):

I don't have enough reputation to comment on @Argenti Apparatus' answer, so I am posting.

> Lastly, the freehub body that the rear sprocket cassette fits on only needs to be compatible with 9 or 10 speed cassettes. (11 speed cassettes require a wider freehub.)

Actually, 11-speed Shimano wheels can take 10-speed cassettes. You just need a spacer behind the cassette. I see that the current version of the Specialized Sport has a 9-speed Sora drivetrain. That might require some double checking as to compatibility. I would guess that again, spacer behind the last cog, but I don't have experience or knowledge of that particular component set.

Comment: Yep, I meant 11 speed compatible hub isn't needed. Edited answer accordingly.

Comment: Gotcha. Rest of the answer is spot on. Apparently now I can comment, so I'm commenting!

Answer (score 0):

In the spec of the bike on the Specialized website it says: 130mm spacing
which is the width of the rear wheel hangers.
Front wheels normally are all the same with 100mm spacing.
So just look for those sizes and you should be fine.